# Vue JS - Changing data in created() and conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a variable `alumnoIncoming` in my component that is `false` by default, and in `created()` I assign a value passed as a query with router push. I have a div which renders conditionally with `v-if` only if that variable is true, but it is always rendering, even when it is false.

The actual value of the variable is correct when I show it with `{{ alumnoIncoming }}`, but if I check it conditionally, like this: `{{ alumnoIncoming ? "incoming" : "outgoing" }}`, it always evaluates as true.

If I change the variable with a method executing when I click a button, the conditionals update correctly.

Here's the complete code of my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="alumnoIncoming">
      esto solo se muestra si alumnoIncoming = true -> {{ alumnoIncoming }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <span >sin i18n : {{alumnoIncoming}} {{ alumnoIncoming ? "incoming" : "outgoing" }} </span>
    </div>
    <div >
    </div>
    <Button label="cambiar" @click="cambiar" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from "primevue/button";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      alumnoIncoming: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.recibeParametros();
  },
  methods: {
    recibeParametros() {
      console.log(this.$route.query);
      this.alumnoIncoming = this.$route.query.alumnoIncoming;
    },
    cambiar() {
      this.alumnoIncoming = !this.alumnoIncoming;
    },
  },
  components: {
    Button,
  },
};
</script>
```

Why is it not getting the correct value of the variable when the component is first rendered?

Comment: What is the value of `{{ alumnoIncoming }}`?  `v-if` tests for truthy values so `1`, `'asdf'`, '{}' (empty object), `[]` (empty array) will all evaluate to true. Unless `alumnoIncoming` is `false, '',  undefined, null, NaN, or 0`, then `v-if` will render that section.

Comment: Okay you made me re-check, it results that the value passed in the router push as query was a string, either `"true"` or "false", not a boolean, if I parse it correctly it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value passed as query in the router push is a string, not a boolean, so it always evaluates to true. To fix this, we have to parse the string:

```
    recibeParametros() {
      this.alumnoIncoming = (this.$route.query.alumnoIncoming === "true");
    },
```